# React Component does not work inside form tag

Tags: html, forms, reactjs, components

I am trying to create an interactive form in React.

I encounter serious issues working with components within the form tag.
Both the component and the button executes all functions outside this form tag but not inside of it.. What do I miss? 
Thanks in advance

```
  <button type="button" onClick={this.addAbholer} >Click me</button>
  <Mycomp />
      <form id="form"  className="wizard-big">
          <Mycomp />
          <button type="button" onClick={this.addAbholer} >Click me</button>
```

Comment: what do you mean by not working, can you explain more ?

Comment: the button is not firing any alert or console log.
the component is rendered correctly but any functions of the component are not working

Comment: Did you check your console? Is that all your code?

Comment: yes it happens nothing. no error no anything. The button is clickable but no function executes

Answer (score 0):

Check this sample working code, i used the same code that you pasted, rendering the button and component inside form, all the events of child component getting triggered and on click of button is also working.

```js
class App extends React.Component{
   addAbholer = (e) => {
      console.log('inside App');
   }
   render(){
      return <form className="wizard-big">
          <Mycomp />
          <button type='button' onClick={this.addAbholer}>Click me</button>
      </form>
   }
}
          
class Mycomp extends React.Component{
   click = () => {
      console.log('inside Mycomp');
   }
   render(){
      return <div onClick={this.click}>Click on Mycomp</div>
   }
}          

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Comment: great example! you gave me the hint that my import jquery steps is avoiding any button action within the function tag...

Comment: no it is not. it seems that  jquery steps is not allowing to use functions within its wizard..